# Remove rows of table based upon Indeterminate value in final column

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a large table in form

```
 exampletable = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6 }, {2, 3, 7, 8, Indeterminate }, {9, 2, 6, 4, Indeterminate }, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4 }}
```

[image]

How to Remove rows of table based upon Indeterminate value in final column to to get result:

[image]

Comment: Try e.g.: `Cases[exampletable, x : {__} /; FreeQ[x, Indeterminate]]`

Comment: Or `DeleteCases[exampletable, {___, Indeterminate, ___}, {1}]` or `Select[exampletable, Not[MemberQ[#, Indeterminate]] &]`

Comment: This [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#139) may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list =
  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6},
   {2, 3, 7, 8, Indeterminate},
   {9, 2, 6, 4, Indeterminate},
   {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}};
```

A few more ways

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, {__?NumberQ}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{__, Indeterminate}}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, Position[list, {__, Indeterminate}]] @ list
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 7, 8, Indeterminate},
       {9, 2, 6, 4, Indeterminate}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}};
```

---

Using `Pick` or `DeleteCases`:

```
Pick[#, MatchQ[#, {__?NumericQ}] & /@ #] &@list

DeleteCases[list, Except[{__?NumericQ}]]

% // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
>  1 & 7 & 3 & 4 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 7, 8, Indeterminate}, {9, 2, 6, 4, 
   Indeterminate}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}}

patt = {___, Indeterminate};

Cases[Except[patt]][list]
DeleteCases[patt][list]
Replace[list, patt :> Nothing, 1]
(Last@# === Indeterminate & /@ list) // Pick[list, #, False] &
```

---

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 7, 3, 4, 4}}